# Unable to verify contracts on polygon Amoy testnet

Tags: hardhat, polygon, contract-verification

I have deployed some contracts on amoy testnet. To verify I followed this [doc](https://www.okx.com/oktc/docs/dev/smart-contracts/verify-contract/verify-contract-using-hardhat) and I have also used the same approach for other chains as well. But in this case I am getting the following error:

```
Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: Failed to send contract verification request.
Endpoint URL: https://www.oklink.com/api/explorer/v1/contract/verify/async/api/okctest
The HTTP server response is not ok. Status code: 404 Response text: {"code":5005,"msg":"API_DECODE_ERROR","detailMsg":"API_DECODE_ERROR"}
```

Unable to find the correct API endpoint url for polygon Amoy testnet, any help is apreciated.

Comment: Seems like some issue with the OKLink Explorer API, as I was able to manually verify the contract via their explorer UI, but not via API. Raised the same issue on Polygon Discord Channel: https://discord.com/channels/635865020172861441/1085625407065301194/1218235167064461333.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to implementation with a combination of these two resources:

- https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomicfoundation-hardhat-verify#adding-support-for-other-networks
- https://www.oklink.com/docs/en/#on-chain-tools-contract-verification-verify-source-code-with-hardhat

In essence, you need to use the correct API URL (not use "okctest" but "amoy") and update your Hardhat config accordingly. However, there may still be issues as pointed out by the other commentor.

*edit*: It doesn't seem like their Explorer API supports verifying source code on Amoy. I just queried both API options with Postman for Polygon mainnet and Amoy, and Amoy has no options, while Polygon mainnet does. Check the images below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've asked regarding this issue on [OKLink Discord channel](https://discord.com/invite/QcywHPgk4S), and they've [responded](https://discord.com/channels/962923641471905792/1191952879733456896/1223922225963335770).

So, the correct configuration to be used in the `hardhat.config.js` would be:

```js
etherscan: {
    apiKey: {
      polygonAmoy: process.env.OKLINK_API_KEY,
    },
    customChains: [
      {
        network: "polygonAmoy",
        chainId: 80002,
        urls: {
          apiURL: "https://www.oklink.com/api/explorer/v1/contract/verify/async/api/polygonAmoy",
          browserURL: "https://www.oklink.com/polygonAmoy"
        },
      }
    ]
  }
```

You can get your `OKLINK_API_KEY` from their [API Management](https://www.oklink.com/account/my-api) dashboard.